# How do I display a WP Option from an array?

Tags: theme-options, settings-api, options

I have a problem displaying the data that I am successfully saving to my database.

```
function create_input_twitter_option() {
    $options = get_option('global_options_arraykey');
    ?><input type="text" name="global_options_arraykey[twitterid]" value="<?php echo $options['twitterid']; ?>" /><?php
}
```

This is what I am putting in my template:

```
<li class="tweat"><a href="<?php echo get_option("twitterid");?>">Visit our twitter Account</a></li>
```

However I am not getting the href value that I see in the database.

Comment: What do you see instead?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!!!

```
      <li class="tweat">
          <a href="<?php $globalOptions = get_option('global_options_arraykey'); echo $globalOptions['twitterid'];?>">Visit our twitter Account</a>
      </li>
```

I got it from this site:
[**Get Option for an Element in an array** - WordPress-Hackers](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/get-option-for-an-element-in-an-array-td25750.html)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what worked for you. Please accept your answer to close the question.

Comment: I will be able to accept it in 2 days. Thanks.